# What is a bootstrap method argument - Java Bytecode

Tags: java, lambda, jvm, bytecode, jvm-bytecode

Bootstrap method with 3 method arguments:

```
SourceFile: "Class.java"
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #883 REF_invokeStatic java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.metafactory:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #884 ()Ljava/lang/Object;
      #885 REF_invokeVirtual java/lang/Module.getClassLoader:()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
      #886 ()Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;
```

Bootstrap methods with single argument:

```
BootstrapMethods:
  0: #284 REF_invokeStatic java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #285 \u0001\u0001
  1: #284 REF_invokeStatic java/lang/invoke/StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants:(Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandles$Lookup;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodType;Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/invoke/CallSite;
    Method arguments:
      #290 \u0001 is not a \u0001
```

I've started looking into Java bytecode and want to know:

- What really is a bootstrap method argument?
- The second argument of the first instance seems to have reference to
  lamda expression. What is that?

**Note:**
This is not about how to determine that an object is a lambda. I just want to understand what is a bootstrap method argument, and its relevance to lambda expressions, ***just by inspecting the bytecode.***

Comment: [Bootstrap method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.23) is not (and cannot be) a lambda expression. Lambda expressions are usually compiled to [invokedynamic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) instruction with one of [LambdaMetafactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html) methods as a bootstrap method.

Comment: @apangin yeah I see. I'm working on a code that assumes the second argument to be some kind of lamda reference. But when compiled with Java 10, I found some bootstrap methods to have just one argument, which breaks the application. Hence the question.

Comment: Like with ordinary methods, the particular method defines the meaning of its parameters. If it is [`LambdaMetafactory.metafactory`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) or `altMetafactory`, it is the target method of a lambda expression or method reference. If it is a different method, like `StringConcatFactory.makeConcatWithConstants`, it has different parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Bootstrap methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.23) are used to [resolve](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-5.html#jvms-5.4.3.6) [`invokedynamic`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokedynamic) instruction.

`invokedynamic` is a general purpose mechanism, not only for lambdas, so it is absolutely possible for a bootstrap method to have an arbitrary number of arguments, which meaning depends on a method being called (see the above links).

`invokedynamic` is also used to compile lambda expressions. In this case the instruction typically refers to [LambdaMetafactory.metafactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#metafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-) or [LambdaMetafactory.altMetafactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html#altMetafactory-java.lang.invoke.MethodHandles.Lookup-java.lang.String-java.lang.invoke.MethodType-java.lang.Object...-) as a bootstrap method. The arguments of these bootstrap methods are described in [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/invoke/LambdaMetafactory.html).